# What is default "" for String[] in annotation declaration?

Tags: java, annotations

What does the `default ""` part mean in the following code?

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] names() default "";
}
```

Is it equal to

```
String[] names() default new String[0];
```

?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] names() default "";
}
```

means that by default `names` will be an array of one empty `String` (`""`).

This is the same as if you've used the array-initializer:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] names() default { "" };
}
```

Additionally, `String[] names() default new String[0];` doesn't compile, because the (default) value of an annotation property must be a constant expression.

As a homework, you can annotate something with `MyAnnotation` and explore its properties with Reflection.

Comment: Instead of `String[] names() default new String[0];` use `String[] names() default {};`

Comment: @foal, `default new String[0]` does not compile, as I've noted. ;)

Comment: Sorry - I meant if you need to have **empty** array use `String[] names() default {};`

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to an array with a single element consisting of the empty string. From the Java Language Specification [section 9.7.1 on annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1):

> If the element type is an array type, then it is not required to use curly braces to specify the element value of the element-value pair. **If the element value is not an *ElementValueArrayInitializer*, then an array value whose sole element is the element value is associated with the element.** If the element value is an *ElementValueArrayInitializer*, then the array value represented by the *ElementValueArrayInitializer* is associated with the element.