# Why getAnnotation(Parsed.class).field() returning String[]?(It should return String, as it is taking input as String)

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, field, univocity

I have following code.

```
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            for (Field field : FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(SpendsInputBean.class)) {
                String[] headerName = field.getAnnotation(Parsed.class).field();
//              ^
//              |____________(Shouldn't this be String)


                .
                .
                .
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

class X {
    @Parsed(field = "Abc")
    private String abc;
}
```

My question is `Parsed(field = "Abc")`, here field is taking `String` as input. But when I am `getAnnotation(Parsed.class).field()` it is returning `String[]` instead of `String`. Why this strange behaviour?

Shouldn't `getAnnotation(Parsed.class).field()` return `String`?

Comment: What version of univocity are you using?

Comment: @rghome I am using 2.5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the UniVocity github repo:

https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/annotations/Parsed.java

There is only 1 method `field()` whose return type is `String[]` and not `String`.

```
 String[] field() default {};
```

**EDIT:**

For the second part of the question i.e. why `Parsed(field = "Abc")` is allowed - this is because:

> If the element type is an array type, then it is not required to use
>   curly braces to specify the element value of the element-value pair

I have quoted the above statement from [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) which you can refer. Additional reference : [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34359703/2458858).

Comment: Then how is this possible? `field = "Abc"` It should be `field = {"Abc"}`, right?

Comment: Ok. So there were 2 parts of your question. I initially answered only first half. See my edit for second part of your question

Comment: @yajiv are you satisfied yet? :)